# Removing a key/value pair from a ConcurrentDictionary given a value

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I have a concurrent dictionary with Ids as keys and tokens as values. There are instances where I will have an Id for which I want to remove tokens, and there are instances where I will have a specific token to remove. What could I call on the dictionary to find the pair with a specified value?

Tokens are unique to Ids.

Comment: Iterate through the collection and find the value, then try to remove the pair based on the key you found.

Comment: Removing *a* value? What if there are many?

Comment: "Token" sounds like pretty unique value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about searching the values and remove them in a loop?

```
var itemsToRemove = dictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals(token));
foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
   dictionary.TryRemove(item.Key, out token);
```